# I am confused about how to use a variable in elisp

Tags: emacs, elisp, quote

I try to set the font as below:

```
  (let ((my:font "WenQuanYi Micro Hei Mono"))
    (when (member my:font (font-family-list))
      (set-face-attribute 'default nil :font my:font :width 'condensed)
      (add-to-list 'default-frame-alist
                   '(font . my:font))))
```

The `set-face-attribute` works fine. I can see the font is set to `WenQuanYi`. But when I check the value of `default-frame-alist`, it shows as `(font . my:font)` and when try to create a new frame (emacsclient), I got this error:

```
*ERROR*: Invalid font: my:font
```

It looks like it try to use the value name as a font name. So I am not sure what's the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quoted list `'(font . my:font)` produces a cons of those two symbols, rather than the value that you want. Instead of quote you can use either backquoting or a call to cons:

```
`(font ,my:font)
```

or

```
(cons 'font my:font)
```

You might be interested in the info pages `(info "(elisp)Quoting")` and `(info "(elisp)Backquoting")`, which explain those constructs in more detail.

On an unrelated note, the emacs lisp lexical conventions for local variables uses hyphens `like-this`, not colons `like:this`.